# What criteria do Rawis ('narrators') of sahih hadith have to fulfil?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

What criteria do Rawis (Arabic for 'narrators') of sahih hadith have to fulfil?

As far as I know, there are six or seven requirements, starting with being adult and mentally fit.

Comment: I suggest changing your title to relate more specifically to your question (everything on Islam SE is an "Islam related question"). Also try stating your question more clearly. For one thing, what is Rawi? Consider that your question should preferably be beneficial to others, in addition to being beneficial for you. Better stating your question is also more likely to attract high quality answers.

Comment: Many scholars gave different criteria as to accepting a narrator.  Keep in mind it's based on a persons preference and not something established by Deen.